# How do return a list with Hibernate search on one col?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I had the following code sample that returns a list of friends from my database use Hibernate and it works get but I know change the function to pass in String which is the user.  How can I change the following code to return all friends that username match the String i pass in?

```
public List<Friend> listFriends() 
{
    return (List<Friend>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(Friend.class).list();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do it.  The first and most straight forward is to use a restriction.

```
public List<Friend> listFriends(String userName) {
    return (List<Friend>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Friend.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("userName", userName) )
        .list();
}
```

Another way would be to use an example.

```
public List<Friend> listFriends(String userName) {
    Friend friend = new Friend();
    friend.setUserName(userName);

    return (List<Friend>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Friend.class)
        .add(Example.create(friend))
        .list();
}
```